# How to show MySQL JSON datatype in .NET Core6

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-6.0

In MySQL I have a column `applicationAttribute` which is of `JSON` datatype. I want to retrieve this column in C#. I would like to show this property as a JSON - not as string.

What would be the correct data type?

My user class:

```
public class user{
   public JsonDocument ApplicationAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

In Swagger example I'm trying to create an example of my user

```
public UserExamples()
    {
        AddExample(new User()
        {
            ApplicationAttributes = JsonDocument.Parse("{\"connect\": {\"ConnectAttribute1\": \"ConnectValue1\", \"ConnectAttribute2\": \"ConnectValue2\"}, \"datalake\": {\"DatalakeAttribute1\": \"DatalakeValue2\", \"DatalakeAttribute2\": \"DatalakeValue2\"}}")
        });
    }
```

When go to swagger, it shows like this:

```
{
   "applicationAttributes": { "rootElement": { "valueKind": 1 }
}
```

I was expecting to see `applicationAttribute` like this

```
{
      "applicationAttributes": {
        "connect": {
            "ConnectAttribute1": "ConnectValue1",
            "ConnectAttribute2": "ConnectValue2"
        },
        "datalake": {
            "DatalakeAttribute1": "DatalakeValue2",
            "DatalakeAttribute2": "DatalakeValue2"
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and we can help you get the rest of the way there. One solution is probably to just create a POCO as the type for `applicationAttributes`.

Comment: I've tried JsonDocument, but it doesn't show the JSON, it shows:  "applicationAttributes": {
    "rootElement": {
      "valueKind": 1
    }

Comment: Alright, but try to show us the code you use to produce the current solution you have (your "string" example). [Edit] your question to add the code.

Answer (score -1):

In any case, you probably want to create classes (POCOs) to represent your `applicationAttributes`:

```
public class Connect
{
    public string ConnectAttribute1 { get; set; }
    public string ConnectAttribute2 { get; set; }
}

public class Datalake
{
    public string DatalakeAttribute1 { get; set; }
    public string DatalakeAttribute2 { get; set; }
}

public class AppAttribute
{
    public Connect connect { get; set; }
    public Datalake datalake { get; set; }
}
```

Then change the type of `ApplicationAttributes` in `User` and deserialize your JSON:

```
public class User
{
   public AppAttribute ApplicationAttributes { get; set; }
}

// ...

public UserExamples()
{
    var jsonFromDb = "{\"connect\": {\"ConnectAttribute1\": \"ConnectValue1\", \"ConnectAttribute2\": \"ConnectValue2\"}, \"datalake\": {\"DatalakeAttribute1\": \"DatalakeValue2\", \"DatalakeAttribute2\": \"DatalakeValue2\"}}";
    AddExample(new User()
    {
        ApplicationAttributes = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AppAttribute>(jsonFromDb)
    });
}
```

Comment: this Jason is dynamic. So I think it should be a 'JObject'